# Cannot use Cloudflare's Rocket Loader in manual mode with wp_enqueue_script

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cloudflare

I have several plugins on my wordpress site which relies on the wp_enqueue_script function. Recently I've had a client who's using Cloudflare who wants to implement Rocket Loader which is an automatic javascript async loader. The issue is that several scripts don't work well with it, which is why I have to disable them from getting asynchronously loaded automatically.

According to the [Rocket Loader wiki](http://www.cloudflare.com/wiki/Rocket_Loader) I need to insert the data-cfasync="false" attribute into the  tag which doesn't seem to be possible with the wp_enqueue_script function.

Are there other ways to define these attributes? If not, is there another way to prevent Rocket Loader from asynchronously loading these specific scripts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloudflare's Rocket Loader + Wordpress -> Ignore scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323986/cloudflares-rocket-loader-wordpress-ignore-scripts)

Answer (score 2):

I'm the engineer who maintains Rocket Loader. Unfortunately without direct access to the HTML of your script tags, there is currently no way for you to manually disable Rocket Loader for individual tags.

One potential solution is that you could use our Page Rules feature to selectively disable Rocket Loader on entire pages that match a basic pattern. If this sounds like it would be a suitable solution for you, log in to your CloudFlare account and check out "Page Rules."

This issue does give me a neat idea: we could provide a WordPress plugin that exposes a CloudFlare Rocket Loader-aware version of wp_enqueue_script. If that is the preferred way for WordPress developers to add scripts to the page, then it seems like that would be a handy plug-in for CloudFlare users.

Finally, if you feel up to it, it would be useful to know about any particular scripts that you know have a problem running through Rocket Loader. We're always trying to make it better and more compatible with the JavaScript out there, so if you could drop me an email at wco [ at ] cloudflare [ dot ] com I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I actually work for CloudFlare. This option should work as well for having [Rocket Loader ignore certain scripts](http://cloudflare.tenderapp.com/kb/cloudflare-website-optimization-and-speed-features/how-can-i-have-rocket-loader-ignore-my-scripts-in-automatic-mode) in automatic mode.

Comment: The Wordpress codex specifies how to create scripts using wp_enqueue script: (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). With this method, Wordpress generates the script tags and allows customization using different parameters. The Rocket Loader page doesn't explain how to implement manual mode on a script by script basis using this method.