# How to add cloudflares data-cfasync="false" attribute to script elements in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, attributes, cloudflare

I have a few files causing issues when i'm using cloudflare's rocket loader. But it improves my site speed by 0.5 sec.

I work inside the Wordpress environment, and as you all properly know, you can't directly edit the html.

**My quesiton is:** Is it possible to **add data-cfasync="false"** attribute via a PHP filter or action to a my scripts?  So it would look like this:

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="/javascript.js"></script>
```

I tried the filter below, but didn't work..

```
    add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {

    if ( 'jquery.min.js' !== $handle )
        return $tag;

    return str_replace( "type='text/javascript' src", ' data-cfasync="false" src', $tag     );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The Handle isn't the filename, but rather the name given in the script enqueue.

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {

    if ( 'jquery-core' !== $handle )
        return $tag;

    return str_replace( "type='text/javascript' src", ' data-cfasync="false" src', $tag     );
}, 10, 2 );
```

The script handles are in \wp-includes\script-loader.php line 751

```
// jQuery.
    $scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core', 'jquery-migrate' ), '1.12.4-wp' );
    $scripts->add( 'jquery-core', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.12.4-wp' );
    $scripts->add( 'jquery-migrate', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate$suffix.js", array(), '1.4.1' );

    // Full jQuery UI.
    $scripts->add( 'jquery-ui-core', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/core$dev_suffix.js", array( 'jquery' ), '1.11.4', 1 );
    $scripts->add( 'jquery-effects-core', "/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/effect$dev_suffix.js", array( 'jquery' ), '1.11.4', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The file `$handle` argument is the unique enqueue name and not the script source name.
You are using the `script_loader_tag` hook with 2 arguments. Use it with 3 arguments and add the `$src` argument so that you won't have to use the `str_replace()` in your callback function.

```php
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_cfasync_data_attribute', 10, 3);
function add_cfasync_data_attribute($tag, $handle, $src) {

    /* add all the scripts that you want to append the data-cfasync="false" in the array */
    if ( !in_array($handle, array('jquery', 'jquery-core' 'your-script-handle') )
        return $tag;

    /* change the script tag by adding data-cfasync="false" and return it. */
    $tag = '<script data-cfasync="false" src="' . esc_url( $src ) . '"></script>';
    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: Arh of course! I'm at my very beginning of PHP. So bare with me here.. How do i find the handle of a script generated by plugins? I have a script generated by Asset Clean Up Pro. 

I tried looking in \wp-includes\script-loader.php but there was nothing with asset cleanup in it.

Comment: Or is it possible to do it via source name instead of handle?

Comment: Yes you could look up the source or you could try some tips from this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/54064/158083